# Postman verify List which does not contain duplicates

Tags: postman

I am getting response which contain large number of records.
I want to make sure doesn’t contain duplicate sessionIds. At the end of each 100 records i am getting next token and want to execute with that for next set of records.
May I know how should I write code for this ?[image]

[image]